# How can i restore my directory structure in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I renamed a few directories in my mercurial repository [not by hg rename command i was not aware of that at that time] just by doing a mv on my linux box , and then I realized that I want the things the way they were before so I did a hg rollback. But it didnt' restore the things to the state they were , how can i get my last commit?

Answer (score 2):

The  `hg rollback` did remove your the latest commit¹. You need to move the directories back with `mv`, and redo you last commit.

When you encounter the same situation again, you can use `hg revert` to replace the changes in the working copy by the content of the current revision. But since your current revision is the revision before your last commit, using revert now would also undo the changes of your last commit.

As a rule of thumb **never** use rollback², since you get the effect of rollback also with the much more safe mq extension.

¹Technically it removed the latest transaction, but it is very likely that your last transaction was a commit.

Comment: I like how you left out the second footnote... :-) I think your rule of thumb is good as it is — people who are new to Mercurial should just not use rollback.

Comment: @MartinGeisler I was inspired by the individual timetables of Deutsche Bundesbahn, where regularly appears remark e), which reads `e)   .`

Answer (score 0):

You want revert. Try

```
hg revert -a
```

or specify a directory if you want to revert just that directory.

Comment: `hg revert` does very likely destroy data after `hg rollback`, since rollback blows away the tip commit.